# notation problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c

When i typed [lat1 = newLocation.coordinate.latitude]; its telling expected : before ] token like that. whats my fault? as i am new to this domain., please ayone guide me.

Thanks In Prior....

Comment: Are you trying to assign `newLocation.coordinate.latitude` into `lat1`, or are you comparing the two?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to compare `lat1` and `newLocation.coordinate.latitude`, the correct statement would be:

```
if (lat1 == newLocation.coordinate.latitude) {
    // do something here
}
```

If you are trying to assign the value of `newLocation.coordinate.latitude` into `lat1`, the correct statement is:

```
lat1 = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
```

If you are trying to do the first thing and the compared variables are floating point numbers, then you probably want to check if they are close enough instead of equality:

```
if (fabs(lat1 - newLocation.coordinate.latitude) < someLittleDistance) {
    // close enough
}
```

…where of course you will have to define `someLittleDistance`.

Comment: Good luck with that.  These are double precision floating point numbers that you are comparing for equality.  It would be better to check if the difference between them is smaller than some small number.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following..

Remove the [] brackets from your line it must be

```
lat1 = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
```

Answer (score 0):

When xCode behaves like this, it probably wants to say that something is the method or it thinks of something like a method. Dot-notation in Objective-C as usual is some kind of equivalent of the setter. For example

ObjectA.property1 = value;

is equivalent of

[ObjectA setProperty1:value];

And in the last case, xCode expects to see : after the setter call and a value after the column.